# multi-module project with dagger: Component depends on more than one scoped component

Tags: android, dagger-2, multi-module

*Note: There seems to be a number of questions about the similar issue but this one is more specific to multi-module app and previously suggested solutions do not work*

I'm starting a multi-module project with one module (Android studio module) for each architectural layer (i.e., Data, Domain, Presentation) and using Dagger 2 to provide dependency injection across the app. Currently I have one Dagger Component for each module which exposes dependencies from each module to other modules. A simplified version looks like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules=[DataModule::class])
DataComponent {
   fun tokenRepository(): TokenRepository
   fun jobRepository(): JobRepository
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules=[DomainModule::class])
DomainComponent {
   fun somethingSingleton(): Something
}

// In Presentation Module
@PerApp
@Component(dependencies = [DataComponent::class, DomainComponent::class])
AppComponent {
   fun tokenRepository(): TokenRepository
   fun jobRepository(): JobRepository
   fun somethingSingleton(): Something
}
```

I got an error saying Dagger component is not allowed to depend on multiple scoped components. However since both Data and Domain components need to provide singletons (like token repository), I have to use something like `@Singleton @Provide fun getTokenRepository...` in `DataModule` which requires `DataComponent` to be also scoped.

I've tried to avoid component dependencies by not creating `DataComponent` and `DomainComponent` and instead having `AppComponent` referencing `DataModule` and `DomainModule` like below.

```
@PerApp
@Component(modules = [DataModule::class, DomainModule::class])
AppComponent {
   fun tokenRepository(): TokenRepository
   fun jobRepository(): JobRepository
   fun somethingSingleton(): Something
}
```

However that does not work unless Presentation module declares (gradle) dependencies for data-related libraries like database or caching library which are used to implement the repository. I feel that would ruin the idea of modulization since those dependencies should not be  a concern of the Presentation layer.

I was wondering if any one had the same issue before and how did you resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: I actually work on a project with the same structure. We don't have a component for each project module, but we have a lot of dagger modules that are included in the application component. All of them have use both `@Singleton` and `@Reusable` have you tried this already?